# Squash groups of pushed commits

Tags: git, squash

[The answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5201642/3765905) explains well how to squash the last few commits after they've already been pushed, but what about the e.g. the last 12 into three groups of four? That is, I have pushed commits 1-12 and would like to now squash them down to three commits. These three squashed commits would contain original commits 1-6, 7-8, and 9-12, respectively. How can I do this?

Bonus points: how can I specify a new commit message for each of the three squashed commits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can squash multiple sets of commits at once:

git rebase -i HEAD~15

```
pick 3f3416d T11 - some issue
pick 23031eb T12 - fix
pick 8239b70 T13 - improvements 
squash e1e23fd T13 - one more fix
squash 200c8c6 T13 - last fix
pick e5b0286 T14 - great feature
pick d18bf1b T15 - removing unused files
pick a1b1821 T16 - refactor part 1.
squash dd090dc T16 - refactor part 2.
squash d87db6b T16 - refactor part 3.
pick da1dd09 T17 - new model of database
pick 39b4ace T18 - restfull api
pick 65521eb T19 - registration form
squash 8924091 T19 - login form
pick b44a25c T20 - new super feature
```

During rebase you will be asked about new commit messages for each group:

**1 group**

```
# This is a combination of 3 commits.
# The first commit's message is:
T13 - improvements

# This is the 2nd commit message:

T13 - one more fix

# This is the 3rd commit message:

T13 - last fix

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# Author:    Your Name <your.email@domain.com>
# ...
```

**2 group**

```
# This is a combination of 3 commits.
# The first commit's message is:
T16 - refactor part 1.

# This is the 2nd commit message:

T16 - refactor part 2.

# This is the 3rd commit message:

T16 - refactor part 3.

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# Author:    Your Name <your.email@domain.com>
# ...
```

**3 group**

```
# This is a combination of 2 commits.
# The first commit's message is:
T19 - registration form

# This is the 2nd commit message:

T19 - login form

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
# Author:    Your Name <your.email@domain.com>
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. To finish it up I had to `git push -f`.

Comment: `git push -f` is necessary if commits in range `8239b70`-`b44a25c` were already pushed. If you last pushed commit would be `pick 23031eb T12 - fix`, this would mean, that you only change your local history. BTW. if you would have to retrive old branch, you can just use old HEAD hash, to create new branch `git checkout b44a25c -b ufff_Its_good_to_have_old_commits_back__branch`

Answer (score 1):

Use
   `git rebase -i [commit-preceding-ones-you want-to-squash`

Mark those that you want to squash `s` (for squash) and those that you want to keep `e` for edit.

It will then interactively squash the intermediate ones, and stop at the others. Then use `git commit -a --amend` to edit the commit message, and `git rebase --continue` to continue.

`man git rebase` should help.